# Why service restart fails with :-restart: Unknown instance:

Tags: command-line, services

```
root@user-desktop:/etc# sudo /usr/sbin/service vsftpd restart    
restart: Unknown instance:
```

Comment: Why running sudo as root?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A typical restart job will attempt to kill an old instance first. What is happening here is that there isn't an old copy to kill.

Comment: So just `/usr/sbin/service vsftpd start` should do it

Answer (score 0):

Try this `sudo /etc/init.d/vsftpd restart`

Comment: This isn't any more useful than using the full path to the 'service' script.